# How to handle nested FrameLayout properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I am using FrameLayouts to overlap image over image, but I can't understand in this particular scenario where my inner FrameLayout doesn't show at the front of another image. Here's the theory:

[image: theory]

and here's the actual thing:

[image: actual]

So here's my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mypage_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cover_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="#CCFF0000" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/cover_photo" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/cover_photo"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@color/aqua"
                android:translationY="-45dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@color/green"
                android:translationY="-40dp" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Have I placed the inner FrameLayout wrong? I don't know how what to do anymore.
Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your FrameLayout has this line: `android:layout_below="@id/cover_photo"`. You can have FrameLayout like this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/cover_photo" >
```

Comment: I forgot to omit that line but that line basically had no effect in the layout since its parent is FrameLayout. I removed that line and nothing changed. Thank for your answer though!

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer, hope it will help. Btw why you have Relative -> Frame -> Relative?? Why you don't have just RelativeLayout?

Comment: Okay, so I got your workaround. Instead of a view below a view and moved it upwards, you aligned it at the bottom and moved it downwards. Brilliant! Btw, I have anything else under the parent RelativeLayout, more ImageView and another RelativeLayout. This is just a fragment from my overall layout. Thank you so much!